# how to overlap html element on flash

Tags: html, flash, overlay, z-index

http://i56.tinypic.com/9u801g.jpg

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td> <ul class="nav">
                <li>Menu</li>
                <li>Menu</li>
                <li>Menu</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Sub Menu</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu</li>
                    </ul>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td> <div class="flash">Flash</div> </td>
</tr>
</table>

.nav li ul{
    postion:absolute;
    z-index:+9999;

}

.flash{
    height:900px;
    width:600px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-999999;
}
```

i am using z-index to overlap html element in the page.

But still sub menu is hiding inside the flash , can anyone help me to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Set the flash wmode to transparent
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html

Comment: we did but still we have the same problem !

Comment: Do you use swfobject? In which browser?

Comment: Note that this doesn’t/didn’t work in Linux and possibly some other places, so you should provide a fallback if the user needs to see the overlapping element to use the site.